# How to add months to a date?

Tags: date, abap

I have been given an assignment like this:

I will have a selection screen input box where user enters date and an other input box where he enters number of months.

I have to do is add the given number of months to date and get the new date.

Example: If entered date is `2/3/2011` and given number of months are `5` i should get `7/3/2011`.

I know that system date variable 'SY-DATUM' has application server date.
And to do date manipulation i can say `SY-DATUM + 2`.i can only add days,how should i add months.

Please give me a head start.Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

An easy way to add a number of months to a date is to use the `MONTH_PLUS_DETERMINE` function module.

Use something like:

```
data: mydate type sy-datum.
mydate = sy-datum.

call function 'MONTH_PLUS_DETERMINE'
 exporting
  MONTHS  = 5
  OLDDATE = mydate
 importing
  NEWDATE = mydate.
```

(`MONTHS` can be negative if you want to subtract.)

There are a lot of other helper functions for date and time calculations. [Useful ABAP Function Modules](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Useful+ABAP+Function+Modules) on the SDN Wiki is a good place to go when you're looking for things like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there a way to do it without function modules..because im still new..i still have'nt covered function modules.

Comment: Well now's the time to learn about calling them. Don't re-invent the wheel. Date/time calcs are tricky. (Although in this specific case, you might be able get away with adding 5 to the month part of a date variable.)

Answer (score 0):

@Mat gave the correct answer. If you want to do it without a function module (whatever your reason may be) and following your example in your question, you can approach your problem like so:

```
data: lv_month type i;
lv_month = sy-datum+4(2).
sy-datum+4(2) = lv_month + 5.
// Check if months are > 12, if so, subtract 12 and increase sy-datum+0(4). Remember to loop if the input can be greater than 12 months.
```

As @Mat mentioned, don't reinvent the wheel. The approach above isn't pretty and function modules get you to your destination faster.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass months and date to below FM to get new date.

```
DATA : LV_NEWDATE TYPE SY-DATUM.
CALL FUNCTION 'BKK_ADD_MONTH_TO_DATE'
                EXPORTING
                  MONTHS  = LV_MONTH " pass months to add
                  OLDDATE = LV_DATE "pass date here
                IMPORTING
                  NEWDATE = LV_NEWDATE. "get new date
```